# Feature is not displaying

Tags: feature

I have created one custom feature and it worked well in my development environment but when i deploy solution in production feature is not visible. feature contains event receiver also.

I also tried with powershell but it is not showing. is there any thing that i am missing here.

Comment: What is the scope of the feature ?

Comment: It's SITE level feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a newly added feature you have created then how you deployed your solution. I had also faced same problem.

If you have updated your solution than it probably not be there. because there are changes in package file.
Retract and remove your solution then add and install your solution.

Remember if new feature added then you have to retract and add the new solution.

If changes are made in feature like page added the update will do the job but in this case you have to deactivate and activate the feature.

If any changes in page then only update solution will do the job.

Comment: yes this is new feature and i am updating the solution with wsp

Comment: uninstall the solution and install new solution and checked if feature is visible or not.

Comment: Do iisreset. May be that will help.

Answer (score 3):

If you update a WSP package that contains a new feature, you have to **install the feature**. This can be done by PowerShell right after the solution update with:

```
Install-SPFeature -path "<name_of_folder_containing_the_new_feature>"
```

(`name_of_folder_containing_the_new_feature` can be found in VS or in the "...\15\templates\features" folder.)

For info, when you first deploy a WSP, all features are installed automatically, witch is not the case for new features during a solution update.

Comment: I was not aware that after updating wsp if i install that feature then it will be visible.

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently added the feature to a solution file already deployed, it will not immediately show up.

You will need to check for existing features using power-shell then install it.
ex.

> 1. Install-SPFeature -ScanForFeatures
> 2. Install-SPFeature FeatureName