# SharePoint 2013 - Custom EventReceiver Feature not appearing in manage feature list

Tags: 2013, feature-activation, sharepoint-standard

I deployed an EventReceiver Solution file on the server. The solution shows globally deployed in Central Administration.

When I go to activate the feature in Manage Site Features in one of the web application, it does not appear there. But strange thing is, it appears in CA's Manage Site Features.

The web application in which I am trying to activate the feature is migrated from 2007 to 2010 to 2013.

I also tried `Install-SPFeature -ScanForFeatures` as mentioned at link [Sharepoint 2010 - feature not appearing in UI](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73871/sharepoint-2010-feature-not-appearing-in-ui) but it does not show that feature in the list.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: [This case](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165623/feature-is-not-displaying) sounds similar to your problem.

Comment: Hi Moe, I have retracted and removed the solution and again installed. But still the same issue.

Comment: Glad to hear! Mark it as an answer to promote the visibility for others looking for a solution for this in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My issue got resolved. This may help someone in future.

**What I tried:**
Since the feature was not getting displayed in "Manage Site Features", I tried to enable feature using powershell.

```
Enable-SPFeature -identity featureID -URL yoursiteURL
```

This command failed with error:

> The feature is not a Farm Level feature and is not found in a Site
>   level defined by the Url [Site Collection Url].

The quick google search for this error returned me answer to my actual issue.

**The Solution**

As I mentioned in my question, the site was upgraded from 2007 to 2010 to 2013. While migrating from 2010 to 2013, we have not done visual upgrade for web application.

And this was the actual issue that feature was not showing in "**Manage Feature List**" of that webapplication.

So I installed WSP file with compatibility option as below

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity "Solution.wsp"  –GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel{14,15}
```

And the magic happened. The feature started to show in the "Manage Site Features"